# how to hide MPAndroidChart pie chart text label if data is 0

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

here is my code for showing text lable for displaying data in pie chart now i want to hide text lable value if data is not preasent for perticular text value, how can i achive that below is my code

```
final ArrayList<PieEntry> yEntrys = new ArrayList<>();
                            //List<String> entries = new ArrayList<>();
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Toase"+response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             Log.d("pieData",response.toString());
                            try {

                                JSONArray jsonarray = (JSONArray) response.get("piechartlist");




                                     for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                                         JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);



                                             String messageSent = jsonobject.getString("messageSent").trim();
                                             String failed = jsonobject.getString("failed").trim();
                                             String rejected = jsonobject.getString("rejected").trim();
                                             String expired = jsonobject.getString("expired").trim();
                                             String unDelivered = jsonobject.getString("unDelivered");
                                             String delivered = jsonobject.getString("delivered");
                                             String ndnc = jsonobject.getString("ndnc");
                                             yEntrys.add(new PieEntry(Integer.valueOf(messageSent), "messageSent"));
                                             yEntrys.add(new PieEntry(Integer.valueOf(failed), "failed"));
                                             yEntrys.add(new PieEntry(Integer.valueOf(rejected), "rejected"));
                                             yEntrys.add(new PieEntry(Integer.valueOf(expired), "expired"));
                                             yEntrys.add(new PieEntry(Integer.valueOf(unDelivered), "unDelivered"));
                                             yEntrys.add(new PieEntry(Integer.valueOf(delivered), "delivered"));
                                             yEntrys.add(new PieEntry(Integer.valueOf(ndnc), "ndnc"));





                                     }



                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();


                            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't add the Entry to the PieChart.

```
if (Integer.valueOf(messageSent) > 0)
{
    yEntrys.add(new PieEntry(Integer.valueOf(messageSent), "messageSent"));
}
```

btw: your JSON parsing is kinda wired. I would suggest POJOs and GSON for parsing JSON Strings.

Comment: its working fine but its also hide bottom legend data ,any solution?

Comment: Either you add it to the piechart and use a custom ValueFormatter to hide the label there but still show it in the legend. The other way would be to not edit the Labels but tweak the legend with a custom legend like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40777867/5268730

Comment: i also found an example usage of the ValueFormatter which targets your problem: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/535

Comment: is there any solution like that adding custom legend in bottom

Comment: look into that stackoverflow answer i mentioned above (haven't tried or needed something like this yet - so just try it out)

Comment: woodii can you provide me example for legend entry

Comment: you should find necessary stuff here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40645322/mpandroidchart-piechart-how-to-set-label-text/40777867#40777867 and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40645322/mpandroidchart-piechart-how-to-set-label-text/40777867#40777867
get the chart's label and add all your entries

Comment: @woodii why you don't like author JSON parse way?) What do POJO ang GSON brings in this situation so it's needs to drag a side libraries?

Comment: @Acuna in my opinion it is much cleaner to use a lib like Gson or Jackson for handling JSON Objects. If you use it you can transform the JSON from a string to a Java object where you can access all properties directly or by getters and setters. Especially if you have to access the properties multiple times it helps a lot in terms of code readability and re-usability.

Comment: @woodii well, but default JSON lib can handle different type of data with various type of methods, for example, `object.getString ("key1")` can get a string value, `object.getLong ("key2")` can get long value, `object.get ("key3")` can get a plain object to work with it like an object. Can anything be more clear especially to use side libraries?

Comment: @woodii that's what I thought :D It's a main reason when apps which have only one activity weight 60 Mb :/

Comment: Sorry for my late response. 60MB? You will face many other Problems before you get to an App with 60MB. GSON is also kinda lightweight. As I mentioned before GSON gets really handy if you have to deal with bigger JSON Objects (maybe with nested classes). You can also use it in combination with HTTP Libraries like OkHTTP/Retrofit and get a java object as response. If you use the JSON properties once it might be ok to use `getString("key")` but if your JSON is bigger and more complex it will be really painful without GSON/Jackson.

Comment: Furthermore your code is much cleaner as you can just use your properties after parsing it with e.g. `BagOfPrimitives obj2 = gson.fromJson(json, BagOfPrimitives.class);` then you can always call `obj2.value1` For more examples look into https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md